# Interactive chart with timeline for WinForms .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, charts, components

I'm looking for WinForms .NET interactive  chart control that will support timeline.

By interactive I mean - something that will allow user to grab a top of a bar and change the value just by dragging it up and down. In some way the bar will behave like a horizontal slider

By timeline I mean something that will allow user to scroll vertically browsing back and future data.

How do you think, does something like that already exists?

Cheers,

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I onced used controls from a company called Steema that allowed you to interactively manipulate charts.  The library was called TeeChart.

Come to think of it, some of the charting controls in National Instruments Measurement Studio libraries also allow you to interactively manipulate graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org). It has some interactive features.

Answer (score 0):

I think **Super 2d/3d Graph Library** from Software Siglo XXI can do what you're looking for.
You can drag vertical bars and adjust their values and more things.

Here's the [link](http://www.softwaresigloxxi.com).